# nativescript-google-maps-sdk: When setting latitude and longitude at runtime the map center isn't correct

Tags: angular, google-maps, plugins, sdk, nativescript

nativescript-google-maps-sdk

I'm setting latitude and longitude values at runtime at OnInit, but the map isn't centered correctly (it is centered at 0º Latitude and 0º Longitude).
I've tried using mapView.updateCamera() but it doesn't refresh the position.
I'm also setting a marker with same latitude and latitude values and this is displayed correctly on the map, so my variables have the correct values (I've also checked with console.log).
Nevertheless, if the latitude and longitude are set at the declaration in the class, the map is centerd well.

Here's map.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import { MapView, Marker, Position, latitudeProperty } from 'nativescript-google-maps-sdk';

// Important - must register MapView plugin in order to use in Angular templates
registerElement("MapView", () => require("nativescript-google-maps-sdk").MapView);

import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  //latitude =  38.735231; //Map is centered correctly if uncommented
  //longitude = -9.146986; //Map is centered correctly if uncommented
  latitude: number;   //Initialized in ngOnInit()!
  longitude: number;  //Initialized in ngOnInit()!

  zoom = 17;
  bearing = 0;
  tilt = 0;
  padding = [40, 40, 40, 40];
  mapView: MapView;

  lastCamera: String;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.latitude = this.route.snapshot.params["lat"];
    this.longitude = this.route.snapshot.params["lon"];
    console.log("1- Lat: " + this.latitude + ", Lon: " + this.longitude); //OK!
  }

  //Map events
  onMapReady(event) {
    console.log('Map Ready');

    this.mapView = event.object;

    console.log("2- Lat: " + this.latitude + ", Lon: " + this.longitude); //OK!

    this.mapView.updateCamera(); //NOT working!!!

    console.log("Setting a marker...");

    var marker = new Marker();
    marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
    marker.title = "JLD Saldanha";
    marker.snippet = "Av. Duque D'Avila, n°46C 1050-053 Lisboa";
    marker.userData = { index: 1 };
    this.mapView.addMarker(marker);
    marker.showInfoWindow();


  }

  onCoordinateTapped(args) {
    console.log("Coordinate Tapped, Lat: " + args.position.latitude + ", Lon: " + args.position.longitude, args);
  }

  onMarkerEvent(args) {
    console.log("Marker Event: '" + args.eventName
      + "' triggered on: " + args.marker.title
      + ", Lat: " + args.marker.position.latitude + ", Lon: " + args.marker.position.longitude, args);
  }

  onCameraChanged(args) {
    console.log("Camera changed: " + JSON.stringify(args.camera), JSON.stringify(args.camera) === this.lastCamera);
    this.lastCamera = JSON.stringify(args.camera);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved:

Issue was that route parameters in angular are strings and the component variables latitude and longitude are numbers so it was not able to properly assign values in OnInit.

Solved problem by converting strings to numbers by adding the + prefix:

```
ngOnInit() 
{ 
  this.latitude = +this.route.snapshot.params["lat"]; 
  this.longitude = +this.route.snapshot.params["lon"]; 
}
```